# Error with simple_form on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

i'm trying to render a form but it's throwing an error and I can't find a reason for it.

controller

```
def new
 @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
 @learning_instrument =  LearningInstrument.new
end

def create

 @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
 @learning_instrument = LearningInstrument.new(learning_instrument_params)

 @learning_instrument.student = @student


 if @learning_instrument.save
   redirect_to student_path(@student)
 else
   render :new
 end
 end


private

 def learning_instrument_params
  params.require(:learning_instrument).permit(:level, :student_id, :instrument_id)
 end
```

this is my form

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@student, @learning_instrument) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>

   <%= f.input :level %>
   <%= f.association :instrument, collection: Instrument.all %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :student, value: @student %>

   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting "can't write unknown attribute `builder`". I've done stuff like this some times and it worked but this time I can't get it to work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't write unknown attribute builder

This is because of this line  `<%= simple_form_for(@student, @learning_instrument) do |f| %>` .You have to define `simple_form_for`  for *nested resources* like below

```
<%= simple_form_for [@student, @learning_instrument] do |f| %>
```

Comment: man do i feel stupid... i didn't notice the parenthesis instead of square brackets